# when i get google key this error come say re try

Tags: android

when i get google api key in Command promt its show an error  retry eror whatis that? plz help me its not obtain akey said  ill legal operation

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keys
tore"C:\Documents and Settings\Nazeer\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass androi
d -keypass android
Illegal option:  -keystoreC:\Documents and Settings\Nazeer\.android\debug.keysto
re
 Try keytool -help

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>
```

Comment: Insert a space after -keystore

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between keystore and "C:....etc

```
-keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Nazeer\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass androi
d -keypass android
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool -list -alias
>   androiddebugkey -keystore"C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Nazeer.android\debug.keystore" -storepass androi d -keypass
>   android

to this

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin>keytool -v -list -alias
>   androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Nazeer.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass
>   android

you need to add space between keystore word and the location because the command line will be read it like this

> -keystoreC:\Documents and Settings\Nazeer.android\debug.keysto re

and it won't recognize the command and I added -v in case you also want to get the MD5 fingerprint

Comment: i do i i get key bnow and is run on simulator working fine but when i deploy app in real android device its not show any map tell me why?

Comment: I think it's another question?maybe you can post another question,don't forget to add your snippet code and the logcat so people can know what's the problem and help you,and could you please accept my answer or TanjaV answer if our answer works for you?thank you :)